# Apache POI insert amount in the next blank line

Tags: java, android, apache-poi

**Update**
The response of CENIC worked but now the spreadsheet is writing the data several times when I press the save button and not just one, follows updated code.

```
//Read the spreadsheet that needs to be updated
        FileInputStream input_document = new FileInputStream(new File("sdcard/AperamApps/DBQ/DBQmestre/historico/historico.xls"));
        //Access the workbook
        HSSFWorkbook my_xls_workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(input_document); 
        //Access the worksheet, so that we can update / modify it.
        HSSFSheet my_worksheet = my_xls_workbook.getSheetAt(0); 



        {


       Row newRow = my_worksheet.createRow(my_worksheet.getLastRowNum() + 1);
       newRow.createCell(0).setCellValue("Unidade Metálica");
       newRow.createCell(1).setCellValue("Local");
       newRow.createCell(2).setCellValue("Posição");
       newRow.createCell(3).setCellValue("Empilhamento");
       newRow.createCell(4).setCellValue("Hora Recebida");        
       newRow.createCell(5).setCellValue("Hora Realizado");

       Row header = my_worksheet.createRow(my_worksheet.getLastRowNum() + 1);
       header.createCell(0).setCellValue(item1);
       header.createCell(1).setCellValue(local1);
       header.createCell(2).setCellValue(posicao1);
       header.createCell(3).setCellValue(emp1);
       header.createCell(4).setCellValue(hr);
       header.createCell(5).setCellValue(timeStamp); 
        }


        input_document.close();

        //Open FileOutputStream to write updates
        FileOutputStream output_file =new FileOutputStream(new File("sdcard/AperamApps/DBQ/DBQmestre/historico/historico.xls"));
        //write changes
        my_xls_workbook.write(output_file);
        //close the stream
        output_file.close();
```

**Print**
[https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/000/537/859/full/Sem_t%C3%ADtulo.png?1446470667](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dhvzq.png)

I am developing an application that writes data into an excel spreadsheet to save a historic , but I'm not getting in any way cause the data to be inserted into the blank next line , follows the code where you desire to accomplish this feat .

```
public void salvar1acao (View view) throws IOException, BiffException, WriteException {

    String item1 = ((String) txtcoluna1.getText().toString());
    String local1 = ((String) txtlocal1.getText().toString());
    String posicao1 = ((String) txtposicao1.getText().toString());
    String emp1 = ((String) txtemp1.getText().toString());

    Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("sdcard/AperamApps/DBQ/DBQmestre/p-comando.xls"));
    WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("sdcard/AperamApps/DBQ/DBQmestre/p-comando.xls"), workbook);

    //Trabalhando com a API POI para escrever de forma mais eficiênte no histórico
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy_HH:mm:ss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

    HSSFWorkbook historico = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = historico.createSheet("Histórico");

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    boolean linha = historico.getSheet(null) != null;



   Row dataRow = sheet.createRow(0);
   dataRow.createCell(0).setCellValue("Unidade Metálica");
   dataRow.createCell(1).setCellValue("Local");
   dataRow.createCell(2).setCellValue("Posição");
   dataRow.createCell(3).setCellValue("Empilhamento");
   dataRow.createCell(4).setCellValue("Hora Recebida");        
   dataRow.createCell(5).setCellValue("Hora Realizado");

    Row header = sheet.createRow(1);
    header.createCell(0).setCellValue(item1);
    header.createCell(1).setCellValue(local1);
    header.createCell(2).setCellValue(posicao1);
    header.createCell(3).setCellValue(emp1);
    header.createCell(5).setCellValue(timeStamp);



    try {
        FileOutputStream out = 
                new FileOutputStream(new File("sdcard/AperamApps/DBQ/DBQmestre/historico/historico.xls"));
        historico.write(out);
        out.close();
        System.out.println("Gravado com sucesso..");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The basic rationale is as follows , if the row has any value , write in row 2, row 2 is writing any value in row 3 and so on. Sorry for my English automatic translation.

Comment: `WritableWorkbook` and `WritableCell` looks like `JExcelAPI` and not like `Apache POI`. Please check your tags!

Comment: Hello,  the application was first developed with the JExcel , however we realize that has fewer features compared to IPO , and now we are working to remove the JXLS gradually . That is currently working with both APIS

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. What isn't working? What errors are you getting? Where is it failing?

Comment: Dear , Gagravarr I need the data to be written line by line, ie I need every time you made ​​this rescue code to find the next blank line for write it, never overwriting an existing value

Comment: You are always writing header and actual data, you probably need to separate opening the file plus writing the header into a method that is only called once and keep the workbook open and add the data-rows then in the loop, not opening/writing/closing once for each data-line!

Comment: Cenic , Header I 've Removed and put a check condition If the Header Already Exist IT Is Not More Written , however OS data continue repeating Below fast You Want What I close the spreadsheet each data entered ? example " Insert line 1 > sheet.close (); " ?

Comment: Hello, There was a data loop early in the code to capture the value of another sheet , the loop was open closed it and now this perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
Row newRow = sheet.createRow(sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1);
```

and then populate the cells via this row. This way you will always add new rows at the end of the Sheet.

Comment: Hello centic, your solution worked , but the data is being written repeatedly , I'm updating the code on my main posting see if you can help me again . Thank you!

Comment: I don't see the new code in the original question. And BTW, please upvote and accept the answer if it answers your question!

Comment: Updated now, even with a print .